# Чистый php или фреймворк?

Tags: php

Чистый php или фреймворк? Уже около 2-х лет программирую на чистом php, но фреймворки даже не юзал. Так что по вашему мнению лучше?

Comment: чистый php, при правильно использовании он быстрее, никто в нем не ковырял кроме вас.
Самый лучший язык тот, который хорошо знаете.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

И что, все два года каждый раз заново пишете маршрутизацию, авторизацию и т.п.? Если нет, то у вас уже подобие фреймворка. Удобно и нравится - используйте.
Если же нет, то возьмите парочку фреймворков и попробуйте на них что-то написать. Всё станет понятно.

А что лучше, это уже вопрос философский. Мне лучше взять готовый фреймворк, изучить его и пользоваться, пока его развивает кто-то другой.

Comment: каждый раз все с нуля, иногда пользуюсь небольшими наработками

Comment: Тогда уделите пару дней изучению фреймворков, а там сделаете выводы. Только не начинайте с каких-то монстров, вроде Zend Studio или Symfony, еще успеете.

Comment: Согласен с xEdelweiss, а вот я например пишу собственную CMS т.к. по моему мнению она очень сильно пригодится, а при необходимости можно будет подрезать часть ненужной функциональности и заточить под конкретные нужды.

Comment: Я написал свой маршрутизатор запросов, прикрутил к нему twig, для работы с БД планирую вкрутить доктрину. Получилось вполне удобно. В маршрутизаторе добавлена простейшая проверка урлов. Допустим, если нам нужно показать какую-то конкретную новость, у которой урл /news/view/1, в маршрутизаторе это будет выглядеть так: /news/view/{id:int}, соответствующий экшн будет вызван в том случае, Если id новости удалось привести к integer. Сам id будет передан в экшн в качестве второго аргумента. Первый аргумент - объект запроса. В принципе, для собственных протейших проектов годный продукт получился.

Comment: И чистый пшп нужно использовать если ты знаешь, чтоделаешь, а не так, как в большинстве вопросов, заданных здесь. Банальной проверки на правильность данных, и экранирования не производится